# Is "STATUS_BREAKPOINT" a Known Error in Rich Text Editor

Tags: richtext-editor

We have a user who's having this problem in Sitecore 9.2.  In the Rich Text Editor (RTE), they insert an image from the media library into their text; when they then click the Accept button to exit the RTE, they get a "STATUS_BREAKPOINT" error dialog.  [image: Screen capture of error]

It gives little information about what's wrong (and the internet implies STATUS_BREAKPOINT is largely used as a blanket category for ambiguous forms of browser errors.)

This does not seem to happen with all images - just some.  Is there a known cause in Sitecore for this problem?

Comment: It happened to us as well, particularly in MS Edge. Has anyone got it anything from Sitecore support yet? If not, I'm happy to report it.

Comment: @Ron Ritchie we are experiencing the same issue with our sitecore 9.2. I was wondering if you were able to figure out why this was happening. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

We also just started encountering this STATUS_BREAKPOINT error today when inserting an image and pressing Accept in the rich text editor in Sitecore 10.2. It occurs in both Microsoft Edge and Google Chrome.

Opening up the browser dev tools, selecting the Network tab, and checking "Disable cache" seems to prevent the error, which can be used as a temporary workaround.

It doesn't generally occur for us the first time someone attempts to insert an image. It occurs pretty reliably after inserting an image on one item, navigating to another item, navigating back to the first item, and attempting to insert an image again.

Comment: Catching up on comments, we're still assessing some of these suggestions:  they seem promising but we're a little limited by our security environments.  The user in question, in particular, is limited in not having development tools in his browsers because the security regime blocks them.  I have a little more leeway and have been able to verify that turning off caching on the Network tab just before submit seems to work, but at this time that doesn't seem an option for our user.

Comment: Late addition:  just after posting my last comment, the user notified me he'd managed to start adding images again using Edge.  (I hadn't been so lucky when I tried that, so it would appear some environment differences are playing a role.)

Comment: "Disable Cache" from the network tab also resolved our issue. Granted, this is a work around, but does get it by. Great observation. Thank you

Comment: Went silent on this for a few weeks because of other priorities.  For what it's worth, we are still having trouble with this.  The dev tools work around seems to work, but is unavailable to our users because of security restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

**Here are a few potential factors to consider:**

**Image size or format:** The issue may be related to specific image files that are causing the error. Check if the problematic images have any unusual characteristics, such as large file sizes, non-standard formats, or special metadata. It's possible that certain images trigger a problem within the RTE's processing or rendering.

**Browser compatibility:** Verify if the issue occurs consistently across different web browsers. It's possible that the problem is specific to a particular browser or its version. Test the RTE functionality with various browsers (e.g., Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer) to see if the error is browser-dependent.

**JavaScript errors:** Use the browser's developer tools to check for any JavaScript errors that might be occurring when interacting with the RTE. These errors could provide more specific information about the cause of the problem. Look for any console error messages related to the RTE or its associated scripts.

If none of these solutions resolve the issue, it's recommended to contact Sitecore Support for further assistance. Provide them with as much information as possible, including the version of Sitecore, the browser used, and the steps taken before the error occurred. They should be able to assist you further in diagnosing and resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

That's an issue with the Chromium build (version 113.x).

As a workaround you can use Firefox for now.

It is already fixed in the latest Chromium (version 114.0.5684.0) but it's only Developer Build for now (16th of May 2023) so you have to wait till it's live.